# Is necessary to restart hadoop after changing log level?

Tags: hadoop

I have changed log4.properties in my running hadoop cluster, should I restart hadoop or it is not neccessary?

Comment: Which Daemon this log4j is it for Mapred/NN/SNN etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you modify a service's log4j.properties file you will need to restart that service for it to take effect.

Comment: unfortunately for all, from INFO to WARN :(